# aria-label is not reading by JAWS in Internet explorer 11 for div role="button"

Tags: html, css, user-interface, internet-explorer, jaws-screen-reader

I have a parent div which has tabindex="0" and aria-label and has child divs. out of which one child div has tabindex="0" and aria-label. JAWS 18 reading this child div aria-label correctly in other browsers but in IE11, it's reading parent div's aria-label.Please help me resolve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could say which div has role = "button". 
So far, this is all I got with JAWS 18 and IE 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent" tabindex="0" aria-label="I am your father">
            0
            <div id="child" tabindex="0" aria-label="so, why mum says it's the butcher?">
                1                
            </div>
            <div id="child" tabindex="-1" aria-label="wrong guy, dude">
                2
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```